QThread not start after obfuscate use pyarmor
My program works without pyarmor.
after obfuscating used pyarmor. I can't not start a thread but gui work.(when I press button for start it not start thread)
I use pyqt5, Qthread. I don't find any errors but the program does not work. Can somebody tell me why?
class Worker(QThread):
   super(Worker, self).__init__()

this code in main:
self.thread = {}
self.thread[i] = Worker(self.tool_pixel, i, name_profile, need_run)
self.thread[i].start()

I try:
print(f'this thread: {self.thread}')

without pyarmor I received:
this thread: {1: <__main__.Worker object at 0x0000025F35828790>}

use pyarmor I received:
this thread: {1: <__main__.pyarmor__111 object at 0x000002B5E50C0B80>}


Did you take your time to carefully check the pyarmor docs? It has a relatively extensive documentation about specific or unexpected cases. There is a PyQt related page, and a threading one too, not to mention all pages related to problem solving and need-to-know issues. Also remember that PyQt is a binding, it uses many underlying Python aspects in order to properly refer and manage C++ objects that may not work well with all this.
